# VSCode user snippet to generate useState for React?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-hooks, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to create a VS code user snippet for `useState()`

Currently I have

```
  "use state": {
    "prefix": "us",
    "body": [
      "const [$1, set${1/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}] = useState($2);",
      "$3"
    ],
    "description": "creates use state"
  },
```

When I enter 'foo' at $1 (position 1) I get:

```
const [foo, setFOO] as useState()
```

However I would like to get:

```
const [foo, setFoo] as useState()
```

How do I change my snippet to work this way?

Comment: Useful snippet!!

Answer (score 24):

You just need to change your transform to `capitalize` like:

`"const [$1, set${1/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}] = useState($2);",`

Comment: As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65846228/capitalize-first-letter-of-vscode-snippet#comment123161116_65846807), in case you're wondering why the 'set' part isn't capitalized, you have to press  `tab` for the capitalization to happen :)

Comment: Tab twice, in my experience

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "*", this character transforms all others to uppercase, without it, you will leave only the first uppercase.

```
  "prefix": "us",
  "body": [
    "const [$1, set${1/(.)/${1:/upcase}/}] = useState($2);",
    "$3"
   ],
  "description": "creates use state"
},
```