# Capitalize first letter of VSCode snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I want to create VSCode snippet to quickly use React's useState. E.g. for a state `open`

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState()
```

I'm currently using

```
"const [ ${1}, set$1 ] = useState()"
```

But this gives me `const [open, setopen] = useState()`. Note the lack of caps on `open`.

I want to be able to just enter the state name `open`, and have the snippet sort out the capitalization for `setOpen`. I know I could use 2 variables, but I don't want to type it out twice since it'll always follow the pattern `[foo, setFoo]`

I know I can do transforms like `${1:/upcase}`, but this capitalizes the entire variable, not just the first letter.

Comment: use `/capitalize`

Answer (score 44):

This should work:

```
"const [ ${1}, set${1/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/} ] = useState()"
```

Comment: Actually, this is enough for the `setOpen` term:  `set${1/(.)/${1:/capitalize}/}` - you only need that first letter.

Comment: For everyone this didn't work for; remember that you need to press tab before the capitalisation is done :)

Comment: And for anyone trying to use this as the 2nd variable, the first $1 is a variable reference, and the 2nd is a local regex reference, so it needs to look like this: `set${2/(.)/${1:/capitalize}/}`