# VS Code snippets capitalize placeholder first letter

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm building code snippets for VS Code. For a specific angular directive I need to lowercase the first letter of a previous placeholder:

```
<ng-container [bsInstanceof]="item">
  <ng-container *bsInstanceofCase="Ava; let ava">{{ Ava.a }}</ng-container>
  <ng-container *bsInstanceofCase="Bebe; let bebe">{{ Bebe.b }}</ng-container>
  <ng-container *bsInstanceofCase="Cece; let cece">{{ Cece.c }}</ng-container>
  <ng-container *bsInstanceofDefault>No match</ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

At the moment, I have the [following code snippet](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap-snippets/snippets/html.json#L60-L71) ([Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MintPlayer.mintplayer-ng-bootstrap-snippets)):

```
"InstanceOf": {
    "prefix": "bs-instance-of",
    "description": "Template-driven `instanceof` switch-case",
    "body": [
        "<ng-container [bsInstanceof]=\"${1:item}\">",
        "\t<ng-container *bsInstanceofCase=\"${2:A}; let ${2/(.*)/${1:/uncapitalize}/}\">{{ ${2/(.*)/${1:/uncapitalize}/}.${3:a} }}</ng-container>",
        "\t<ng-container *bsInstanceofCase=\"${4:B}; let ${4/(.*)/${1:/uncapitalize}/}\">{{ ${4/(.*)/${1:/uncapitalize}/}.${5:b} }}</ng-container>",
        "\t<ng-container *bsInstanceofCase=\"${6:C}; let ${6/(.*)/${1:/uncapitalize}/}\">{{ ${6/(.*)/${1:/uncapitalize}/}.${7:c} }}</ng-container>",
        "\t<ng-container *bsInstanceofDefault>${8:No match}</ng-container>",
        "</ng-container>"
    ]
},
```

which, [according to this answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65846807/8941307), should totally work. But the value of the  placeholder is just being copied as-is:

[image: VS Code snippet placeholder not transformed]

Note that the comments in the linked question, state that the index before `/uncapitalize` is the regex match group index.
Why is this not working as expected?

Comment: where in the linked question does the word `uncapitalize` appear

Comment: Is your `${3:a}` somehow derived from `$2`?  And are you worried about an input like `BeBe` - with another capital letter somewhere after the first letter?

Comment: No, placeholder 3 is the property of class `A`. The casing is a good point. I've tested it, and it works as I would expect: if I type `BeBe` and tab out of the placeholder, VS Code changes it to `beBe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uncapitalize` is not part of the snippet syntax.

You have to split the string in 2:

- first character
- the rest

```json
"InstanceOf": {
  "prefix": "bs-instance-of",
  "description": "Template-driven `instanceof` switch-case",
  "body": [
      "<ng-container [bsInstanceof]=\"${1:item}\">",
      "\t<ng-container *bsInstanceofCase=\"${2:A}; let ${2/(.)(.*)/${1:/downcase}$2/}\">{{ ${2/(.)(.*)/${1:/downcase}$2/}.${3:a} }}</ng-container>",
      "\t<ng-container *bsInstanceofCase=\"${4:B}; let ${4/(.)(.*)/${1:/downcase}$2/}\">{{ ${4/(.)(.*)/${1:/downcase}$2/}.${5:b} }}</ng-container>",
      "\t<ng-container *bsInstanceofCase=\"${6:C}; let ${6/(.)(.*)/${1:/downcase}$2/}\">{{ ${6/(.)(.*)/${1:/downcase}$2/}.${7:c} }}</ng-container>",
      "\t<ng-container *bsInstanceofDefault>${8:No match}</ng-container>",
      "</ng-container>"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This seems to work fine. I have to add that you have to `tab` beyond the placeholder before the uncap happens. It works like a charm now...